# Adding a method to an object that is inside of a function in js

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

Hi this is from a challenge I was working on. Is there any way i can add the introduce method to the `personStore` object without using the keyword this. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

> Using Object.create
>
> **Challenge 1/3**
>
> Inside `personStore` object, create a property greet where the value is a  function that logs "hello".
>
> **Challenge 2/3**
>
> Create a function `personFromPersonStore` that takes as input a name and an age. > When called, the function will create person objects using the Object.create  method on the `personStore` object.
>
> **Challenge 3/3**
>
> Without editing the code you've already written, add an `introduce` method to the `personStore` object that logs "Hi, my name is [name]".
>
> **Side Curiosity**
>
> As a side note, was curious if there was a way to add the introduce method to the person object that sits inside of the personFromPersonStore function.

my solution:

```
var personStore = {
    // add code here
  greet: function (){
    console.log('Hello');
  }
};

function personFromPersonStore(name, age) {
  var person = Object.create(personStore);
  person.name = name;
  person.age = age;
  person.greet = personStore.greet;
  return person;    
};

personStore.introduce = function () {
  console.log('Hi, my name is ' + this.name)
}

//Challenge 3 Tester
sandra.introduce(); // -> Logs 'Hi, my name is Sandra
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but using `this` is a lot simpler.

This code passes the `name` property as an argument, but as the property is already accessible to the `introduce` function as an internal property via `this`, it is a bit wasteful.

```js
var personStore = {
    // add code here
  greet: function (){
    console.log('Hello');
  }
};

function personFromPersonStore(name, age) {
  var person = Object.create(personStore);
  person.name = name;
  person.age = age;
  person.greet = personStore.greet;
  return person;    
};

personStore.introduce = function (nm) {
  console.log('Hi, my name is ' + nm)
}

person1=personFromPersonStore('Fred',21);
person1.introduce(person1.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
personFromPersonStore("whatevername","whateverage").name
```

instead of this.